# tlmgr does not work at all

Tags: tlmgr, update

Here's the problem: As i was writing an essay on my computer using latex i noticed that the editor was giving me an error for the packages tikz and cancel( i'm using kile')

```
error: the file [tikz or cancel].sty was not found.
```

I installed the version from the website `https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html`.There's a clickable link that downloads a tar.gz file. I imagined that the freaking version on this installer was the 2020 version but aparently it's not. SO i though "no bigie, just install the packages manually using tlmgr"...

So i open the terminal, type `tlmgr install tikz` and:

```
tlmgr install tikz
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)

/usr/bin/tlmgr: unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5
```

I've tried updating my version of TeX but when I run the script that is provided in the `https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html`

```
 sh update-tlmgr-latest.sh 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing TeX Live Manager Updater  100%  
./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.
./runme.sh: (no tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb and/or tlpkg/tlpobj/.)
./runme.sh: Please set your PATH as needed, otherwise it's hopeless.
```

The first two errors idk what they mean but the last one says tha my PATH env variable is not defined correctly, but

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:
/snap/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:/usr/share/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:
```

says otherwise.

and i cannot install any package because my version of tex is too old

So.. i'm stuck.. help?

Comment: you have `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:` in your path which suggests you have installed texlive from tug? but you have it too late after /usr/bin so it is not being used, you are using the debian system texlive. you can update the system texlive by apt or whichever package manager you use at the linux level, or if you hav einstalled a vanilla texlive put it at the front of your path.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux` in your path which suggests you have installed texlive from TUG? but you have it too late after `/usr/bin` so it is not being used. You are using the debian system texlive.

You can update the system texlive by `apt` or whichever package manager you use at the linux level, or if you have installed a vanilla texlive from TUG put it at the front of your path.

Comment: A follow up question. I did install texlive with `apt`, but my texlive does not seem to be installed in `\usr\local\texlive\` I see a `\usr\share\texlive` but in there i see a `debian` subfolder. Do i need to install for source? Any suggestion?

Comment: @geguze  if you install the debian texlive via apt it will be in the standard bin directory not /usr/local. (the site doesn't really support followup questions in comments, post a question as a question if you have a problem)