# tlmgr "unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5"

Tags: texlive, texlive-2019

I have a very similar problem as discussed in the post [TEX564734](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/564734/tlmgr-does-not-work-at-all). I am on ubuntu 20.04 and the installation via `sudo apt install texlive` installed a debian version in the folder `/usr/share/texlive`. The installed version is texlive 2019 (issuing `pdflatex` I get `Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian)`.

I then executed:

`tlmgr init-usertree`

however when I then try to install a new packages I get:

`unexpected return value from verify_checksum: -5`

In a different post, [TEX537810](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/528634/tlmgr-unexpected-return-value-from-verify-checksum-5/537810#537810), I saw that a solution is to update `tlmgr` but that does not work either.

`kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT`

returns `/` which does not seem right. Indeed when I tried `sudo env PATH="$PATH" ./update-tlmgr-latest.sh` i get an error `./runme.sh: Cannot find TeX Live root using kpsewhich --var-value=SELFAUTOPARENT.`. I added to the `PATH` the director `/usr/share/texlive`. Maybe that's not sufficient given the Debian version? This director is the first in the `PATH`.

`tlmgr repository list` provides two repos `http://contrib.texlive.info/current (tlcontrib)` and `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet (main)`

`tlmgr key list` reports a key that does not seem to have any expiration date `rsa2048 2016-03-19 [E]` plus another one I added from the repo maintained by Norbert Preining (`tlcontrib`) that has expiration date 2021-03-01.

At this point I am not sure what do to next to be able to install packages.

Comment: If you installed TeX Live via `apt` from Linux/Debian/Ubuntu/... repositories, you can use `tlmgr` only for a very limited set of operations. In particular packages should usually *not* be installed via `tlmgr` (for starters, you have TeX Live 2019, but `tlnet` currently serves TeX Live 2020). All TeX Live packages available at the time TeX Live was packaged for your distribution are available via `apt`. They are split into collections, so you 'just' need to find out which collection contains the package you want.

Comment: @moewe: Thanks! I will try to see if I can 'find' the packages, but that looks certainly painful. Fortunately, I was able to manually install the packages by creating the correct tree structure in my home directory under `texmf`. Wanted to mention this last possibility in case someone runs into the same problem and does not find the correct package to install with `apt`.

Answer (score 1):

As moewe has pointed out, you should not install packages via `tlmgr` if you have installed TeX Live via `apt`.

Search the collection that includes you desired package via `apt-cache search`. For example, let's search for a collection that includes the beamer package:

```
apt-cache search beamer
```

Select a matching texlive collection and install it via `apt`:

```
sudo apt install texlive-latex-extra
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!